# Slicer only corresponds to table not my chart - Mac Excel 16

Tags: pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-chart

I have inserted a pivot table based on the data range I want to use. From there, I have selected the data in the table and inserted a chart. I then insert a slicer, but when I select the category it does not change the data in the chart but rather the table only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you are creating the chart and pivot separately ?

You need to create them together, see image below.

[image]

Then you can insert slicers that will update both the pivot and the chart simultaneously, see below.

[image]

For mac see below link:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac/pivot-chart-in-excel-2016-mac-version/87caf52f-4755-469d-bb7a-2fce5774099e?auth=1

Comment: im not given the option to add both, in fact my workbook doesn't look even similar to yours. I'm finding that the slicer function for charts is not available for Mac Excel?

Comment: ahh, you did not mention you were using mac, see update to my answer